# How do I tile and count all the rectangles that will fit inside a circle?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been tasked with creating a tool that will allow my manager to estimate how many custom-sized rectangles they can fit inside a circle with a specific diameter with a 0.1mm gap between. This is to calculate the yield of a silicon wafer cut into rectangles of the same size and orientation. The count is needed to provide a quote to the client, and the visualization aids with the actual cutting of the wafer.

I've new to javascript, but I got as far as the form, the circle, and one rectangle, but I can't seem to tile rectangles into the remainder of the circle.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Circle and Rectangles</title>
    <style>
        .circle {
            width: 100mm;
            height: 100mm;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: lightgray;
            position: relative;
        }
        .rectangle {
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function calculate() {
            var circleDiameter = document.getElementById("circle-diameter").value;
            var rectangleWidth = document.getElementById("rectangle-width").value;
            var rectangleHeight = document.getElementById("rectangle-height").value;
            var gap = document.getElementById("gap").value;

            var circleRadius = circleDiameter / 2;
            var rectangleDiagonal = Math.sqrt(rectangleWidth ** 2 + rectangleHeight ** 2);
            var maxRadius = (rectangleDiagonal + gap) / 2;
            var centerX = circleRadius;
            var centerY = circleRadius;

            var rows = Math.floor(circleDiameter / (rectangleHeight + gap));
            var columns = Math.floor(circleDiameter / (rectangleWidth + gap));
            var totalRectangles = rows * columns;

            var count = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    var rectangle = document.createElement("div");
                    rectangle.classList.add("rectangle");
                    var left = centerX + ((j - (columns - 1) / 2) * (rectangleWidth + gap)) - rectangleWidth / 2;
                    var top = centerY + ((i - (rows - 1) / 2) * (rectangleHeight + gap)) - rectangleHeight / 2;
                    var distanceFromCenter = Math.sqrt((left - centerX) ** 2 + (top - centerY) ** 2);
                    if (distanceFromCenter <= circleRadius - maxRadius) {
                        rectangle.style.width = rectangleWidth + "mm";
                        rectangle.style.height = rectangleHeight + "mm";
                        rectangle.style.top = top + "mm";
                        rectangle.style.left = left + "mm";
                        var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
                        var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
                        var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
                        rectangle.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
                        document.querySelector(".circle").appendChild(rectangle);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(count);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="circle-diameter">Circle Diameter:</label>
    <input type="number" id="circle-diameter" value="100"> mm
    <br>
    <label for="rectangle-width">Rectangle Width:</label>
    <input type="number" id="rectangle-width" value="7"> mm
    <br>
    <label for="rectangle-height">Rectangle Height:</label>
    <input type="number" id="rectangle-height" value="9"> mm
    <br>
    <label for="gap">Gap:</label>
    <input type="number" id="gap" value="1"> mm
    <br>
    <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <br><br>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So just to clarify the requirements here:  all of your rectangles are the same size, or can they be different sizes?  And you want to know how many of these rectangles can fit completely inside some circle of radius R, without being cut off at all?  Can your rectangles be aligned in different ways (eg, rotated 90 degrees, or 45 degrees, etc)?  Do you also need to maintain a gap between the rectangles and the border of the circle, or are they allowed to touch?   Does the result need to be an exact maximization, or is some fudging ok (asking because you used the word "estimate")?

Comment: Do you really need a UI component here (eg, could this just be a console program)?  If so, what is the manager going to do with a picture of a circle with a bunch of rectangles inside it...?  How familiar are you with searching algorithms like BFS/DFS?  Can you ballpark how many rectangles might be fitting into one of your circles (eg, if the expected use case is thousands or millions of rectangles, then performance may become an issue)?

Comment: Probably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365007/packing-fixed-size-rectangles-inside-a-circle-with-the-biggest-zoom) lays out an algorithm that you could use (depending on your exact requirements).  High-level, the suggested algorithm makes sense to me though, and should be fairly straightforward to implement (certainly its much better than BFS/DFS as I suggested above, but again, depends on your requirements).